# Call requires API level 21, current min is 8

Tags: java, android

Call requires API level 21, current min is 8. Even though I set my min SDK to 21, it still shows this error.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
          android:targetSdkVersion="23"
          android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
```

Comment: Where did you set? can you post your gradle file where you set it?

Comment: can you provide more details about your errors, a picture will help.

Comment: Check your build.gradle file in app folder for minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 4):

The sdk version values in the Manifest.xml will be overridden by the values in the build.gradle file.

Please change the code in your build.gradle file to this.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for your project properties file. This may be in your root folder, called *project*.properties. Try adding this line, you should have it in any case:

```
target=android-23
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Calls requires API level 21.(current mint is 15)"...`

I solved this error by simply

> set->
>   compileSdkVersion 27 
>   minSdkVersion 15 
>   TargetSdkVersion 27

After setting these attributes, I simply go main activity where I face a problem.

I just click on my error and from suggestions I choose
**Add @TargetApi(LOLLIPOP) Annotation**
and through this process, I solved my issue..